# "MAXIFS" on large amount of data / finding max temperature per day

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a large amount of temperature data spanning 3 years, approx 340,000 rows. It has a temperature reading every hour, and for 12 different geographical locations, so 24 readings per day for each location.

I'm trying to calculate the maximum temperature for each day in each location, and place these in a simple grid of dates as rows and locations as columns, and have been using a workaround array formula that's basically intended to be a "MAXIFS" formula, as follows:

{=MAX(IF(J:J=A6, IF(K:K=B5, I:I)))}

(Where A6 is the date, B5 is the location, column J holds all the dates in the temperature data, column K has the location IDs, column I has the actual temperature readings.)

This seems to work for a few hundred rows or so, but anything above that I get the "Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas" error.

I realise this is a very resource-intensive way of calculating this, so is anyone aware of another way I could go about this?

I had the thought of trying to run a RANK() formula on the temperature data, ranking each temperature reading within that day and basing the range on dynamic references, but haven't quite figured it out yet, and I have the feeling that this will be just as resource-heavy and likely to cause calculation problems.

Comment: Have you tried pivot table? That should be the most efficient way for your calculation. If you post some sample data we could suggest some more specific steps.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of using Pivot Table! Got so bogged down in the details of trying to do it with formulas. Thanks very much - if you want to post this as an answer I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally these kind of problem can be easily solved by pivot table.

You can set row and column headers for grouping and get the max of your data in the data part.